# Xamarin Forms - Access Embedded Image from UWP Custom ImageRenderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, embedded-resource

I searched a lot on Internet but it doesn't seem that Google has the answer..

So how can I access an Embedded image (in the PCL part), from my UWP project part?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` to get access to PCL-based assembly from the "native" platform assembly and thus its embedded resources.

#### Example:

Dependency Interface:

```
public interface IResource
{
    bool CheckEmbeddedAccess(string imageName);
}
```

Platform Implementation:

```
public bool CheckEmbeddedAccess(string imageName)
{
    var callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    System.IO.Stream file = callingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imageName);
    if (file != null)
    {
        // do something with stream 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage from PCL:

```
var exists = DependencyService.Get<IResource>().CheckEmbeddedAccess("ImageResource.Face.png");
```

**Note:** Make sure you are using the correct "Resource ID" as by default your resource gets appended with the assembly name (dot notation) when you add it to your project. To view all the actual resource ids, use this in your dependency service implementation to iterate over them:

```
foreach (string resourceName in callingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine(resourceName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @SushiHangover !

I'm working with embedded image but because it's a renderer, I then have the `SourcePath` into my object. Si I did like it and it finaly works :)

```
using ImageCircleProject.CustomControl;
using ImageCircleProject.UWP.CustomRenderer;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomImageCircle), typeof(CustomImageCircleRenderer))]
namespace ImageCircleProject.UWP.CustomRenderer
{
public class CustomImageCircleRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomImageCircle, Ellipse>
{
    private CustomImageCircle customImageCircle;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomImageCircle> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {

        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            customImageCircle = e.NewElement as CustomImageCircle;

            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
            SetNativeControl(ellipse);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected async override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var min = Math.Min(Element.Width, Element.Height) / 2.0f;
            if (min <= 0)
                return;

            double radius;
            if (Element.Width < Element.Height)
            {
                radius = Element.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                radius = Element.Height;
            }

            Control.Width = radius;
            Control.Height = radius;

            // That will be our fallback fill if can't make sense of the ImageSource.
            Control.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 52, 152, 219));

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = null;

            // Handle file images
            if (Element.Source is FileImageSource)
            {
                FileImageSource fi = Element.Source as FileImageSource;
                string myFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, fi.File);
                StorageFolder myFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(myFile));

                using (Stream s = await myFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myFile)))
                {
                    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await s.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                }

            }
            // handle embedded images
            else if (Element.Source is StreamImageSource)
            {
                using (Stream s = await GetStreamFromImageSourceAsync(Element.Source as StreamImageSource))
                {
                    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await s.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                }
            }
            // Handle uri images
            else if (Element.Source is UriImageSource)
            {
                bitmapImage = new BitmapImage((Element.Source as UriImageSource).Uri);
            }

            if (bitmapImage != null)
                Control.Fill = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = bitmapImage };
        }
    }

    private static async Task<Stream> GetStreamFromImageSourceAsync(StreamImageSource imageSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (imageSource.Stream != null)
        {
            return await imageSource.Stream(cancellationToken);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**I then handle it with this part**

```
// handle embedded images
else if (Element.Source is StreamImageSource)
{
    using (Stream s = await GetStreamFromImageSourceAsync(Element.Source as StreamImageSource))
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        await s.CopyToAsync(memStream);
        memStream.Position = 0;
        bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
    }
}
```

So because a `StreamImageSource` already exist, I use it to recreate the image